# Place for jsp page, where it will be available for spring and <welcome-file-list>?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

My web application using spring. I want, that my application start with started page home.jsp
therefore I add to web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

File home.jsp must located in webapp. If I move this file, web apllication will not find it. I want to use this page from spring. It forced me copy this file to webapp/WEB-INF/views.

Can I use single home.jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

[It's Oracle's specification.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configurejsp.html#wp157851)

> Welcome files are defined at the Web application level. If your server is hosting multiple Web applications, you need to define welcome files separately for each Web application. You define Welcome files using the welcome-file-list element in web.xml. (The web.xml file is located in the WEB-INF directory of your Web application.)

Answer (score 1):

You can map your spring app to respond to /. That way you can have both welcome page and your spring files accessible.

Then you wouldn't (be able to) use welcome-file config element, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

element you must store your ***"home.jsp"*** file in the root folder.

***means webapp(root folder)/home.jsp***